# How to use ViewSwitcher on only one row

Tags: android, android-listview, viewswitcher

I am trying to add an viewSwicther to a listview. What I want is that when an item is clicked for a long time, that field will be transformed to an EditText. At the moment it's always the element at the top of the list that tranforms from TextView to EditText.
I have a custom adapter based on an baseAdapter.

The code is shown below;

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int size = findSizeOfArray();
            if(position == (size-1)){
                ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.my_switcher);
                switcher.showNext();
                preAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    preAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to find and set your LongClick position as you did but you should pass this position to your Custom Adapter , then inside your Custom Adapter you catch this position and set a GlobalVariable to hold your selection Position , then in `getView()` function you can check that if getView() related position is equal to your Selected position which you receive from your Main Activity , then you can implement your `ViewSwitcher` inside of your List `getView()` function